# Grouping a collection of object based on on value in objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

We have an array that contains objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":29751,
    "refId":20293494,
    "pCode":712,
    "paymentDate":140101,
    "title":"Sample title",
    "heading":"A heading",
    "value":4214000,
    "remainder":429740000,
    "createdAt":"2023-01-31T07:34:29.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id":29752,
    "refId":20293495,
    "pCode":712,
    "paymentDate":140102,
    "title":"Sample title",
    "heading":"A heading",
    "value":4214000,
    "remainder":429740000,
    "createdAt":"2023-01-31T07:34:29.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id":29753,
    "refId":20293496,
    "pCode":712,
    "paymentDate":140103,
    "title":"Sample title",
    "heading":"A heading",
    "value":4214000,
    "remainder":429740000,
    "createdAt":"2023-01-31T07:34:29.000Z"
  }
]
```

So thing is to group items based on `paymentDate`. I mean to create a new array of objects and when main array maps, if `paymentDate` is `140101`, goes in `140101` item. The result would be like this:

```
{
  "140101":[
    {
      "id":29751,
      "refId":20293494,
      "pCode":712,
      "paymentDate":140101,
      "title":"Sample title",
      "heading":"A heading",
      "value":4214000,
      "remainder":429740000,
      "createdAt":"2023-01-31T07:34:29.000Z"
    }
  ],
  "140102":[
    {
      "id":29752,
      "refId":20293495,
      "pCode":712,
      "paymentDate":140102,
      "title":"Sample title",
      "heading":"A heading",
      "value":4214000,
      "remainder":429740000,
      "createdAt":"2023-01-31T07:34:29.000Z"
    }
  ],
  "140103":[
    {
      "id":29753,
      "refId":20293496,
      "pCode":712,
      "paymentDate":140103,
      "title":"Sample title",
      "heading":"A heading",
      "value":4214000,
      "remainder":429740000,
      "createdAt":"2023-01-31T07:34:29.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

What we are looking for is to handle this situation dynamically. Couse this is not the only situation. we may have a larger data with more `paymentDate`s.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
const newArray = {};

items.map((item) => {
   if (newArray.hasOwnProperty(item.paymentData)) {
      newArray[item.paymentData].push(item);
   } else {
      newArray[item.paymentData] = [];

      newArray[item.paymentData].push(item);
   }
});
```